# Ubuntu problem when trying to copy ISO

Tags: iso, cp

I have dowloaded an ISO image and I am trying to follow the installation instructions.

I have mounted the ISO using the following command:

```
sudo mount -o loop /home/pinkd/Desktop/isofile.iso /media/iso
```

Then when I execute the next command I get this message. What am I doing wrong?

```
cp /media/iso/ /tmp/folder1/
cp: omitting directory '/media/iso/'
```

Comment: What instructions are you following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are copying directory, you have to tell `cp` you want to copy its content. Thus, flag `-r` (recursive) is required, or, as stated in comment, use path `/*` , which means every file in that directory (please note, that if the directory contains other directories, it will omit them).

TL;DR: Use `-r` flag, e.g.

```
cp -r /media/iso /tmp/folder1
```